# rewrite file to wordpress

Tags: plugins, url-rewriting

I have in my plugin dir a endpoint.php and need to rewrite like this:

```
http://domain.com/API/endpoint.php
```

This is the code I've used:

```
add_rewrite_rule( 'API/endpoint.php', 'myplugin-path/endpoint.php', 'top' );
```

When I print the `$wp_rewrite` global I got this:

```
[non_wp_rules] => Array
    (
        [API/endpoint.php] => http://mydomain/myplugin-path/endpoint.php
    )
```

But still not work, any Ideas?

Comment: updated your question with the code you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress rewrite mechanism works in a different way, not like .htaccess rewrite rules. More information about it you can find in [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/) ([Rewrite API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API), [WP_Rewrite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite), etc.). But fast work around could be the following:

First of all we need to register our query var and rewrite rule:

```
function myplugin_add_query_var( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'myplugin_api';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'myplugin_add_query_var' );

function myplugin_update_rewrite_rules( $rules ) {
    $newrules = array();
    $newrules['api\/endpoint\.php$'] = 'index.php?pagename=api&myplugin_api=1';
    return $newrules + $rules;
}
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'myplugin_update_rewrite_rules' );
```

To complete registration of rewrite rule, we need to flush rules on activation/deactivation of you plugin:

```
function myplugin_activate() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_activate' );

function myplugin_deactivate() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_deactivate' );
```

A piece of magic to make rewrite rules working correctly :D

```
function myplugin_a_piece_of_magic_on_init() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->use_verbose_page_rules = !preg_match( "/api\/endpoint\.php$/i", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
}
add_action( 'init', 'myplugin_a_piece_of_magic_on_init' );
```

And finally check if our query var presents on wp action:

```
function myplugin_check_query_var( $wp ) {
    if ( array_key_exists( 'myplugin_api', $wp->query_vars ) ) {
        // do api stuff here ...
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'myplugin_check_query_var' );
```